# Best way to store dictionary in a file and load it partially?

Tags: python

Which is the best way to store dictionary of strings in file(as they are big) and load it partially in python. Dictionary of strings here means, keyword would be a string and the value would be a list of strings.

Dictionary storing in appended form to check keys, if available not update or else update. Then use keys for post processing.

Comment: Use `pickle` for saving objects to file

Comment: Perhaps YAML or JSON could be an option for you. Check them out.

Comment: Do you need incremental read access for the strings, or is it acceptable to load the entire string each time?

Comment: Without knowing more, I have to wonder if some kind of database might be a better option than a regular file. Even SQLite, which is included with Python and doesn't require any complicated server configuration, might help.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a dictionary is stored in JSON.

I'll leave here a link:

[Convert Python dictionary to JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661051/convert-python-dictionary-to-json-array)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write the dictionary to a text file, and then create a new dictionary that only pulls certain keys and values from that text file.

But you're probably best off exploring the json module.

Here's a straighforward way to write a dict called "sample" to a file with the json module:

```
import json
with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(sample, fp)
```

On the loading side, we'd need to know more about how you want to choose which keys to load from the JSON file.

Comment: The problem with that is that it loads everything into memory, which appears to be a problem due to the size of the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are great, but i hate using JSON, i have had issues with pickle before that corrupted my data, so what i do is, i use numpy's save and load

To save `np.save(filename,dict)`

to load `dict = np.load(filename).item()`

really simple and works well, as far as loading partially goes, you could always split the dictionary into multiple smaller dictionaries and save them as individual files, maybe not a very concrete solution but it could work

to split the dictionary you could do something like this

```
temp_dict = {}
for i,k in enumerate(dict.keys()):
    if i%1000 == 0:
        np.save("records-"+str(i-1000)+"-"+str(i)+".npy",temp_dict)
        temp_dict = {}

    temp_dict[k]=dict[k].value()
```

then for loading just do something like

```
my_dict={}
all_files = glob.glob("*.npy")
for f in all_files:
     dict = np.load(filename).item()
     my_dict.update(dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is for some sort of database type use then save yourself the headache and use [TinyDB](https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It uses JSON format when saving to disc and will provide you the "partial" loading that you're looking for.

*I only recommend* `TinyDB` *as this seems to be the closest to what you're looking to achieve, maybe try googling for other databases if this isn't your fancy there's TONS of them out there!*