# How to convert a dictionary into a javascript object

Tags: python

I want to convert a dictionary like this:

```py
{
 "name": "Paul",
 "age": "20",
 "gender": "male"
}
```

to this :

```js
{
 name: "Paul",
 age: "20",
 gender: "male"
}
```

Basically the same as a JSON, but the object properties cannot be wrapped around quotes.
Is it possible to do that in Python?

Comment: you need to use javascript to convert a string dictionary to json object, (not a js guy)

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot"? The quotes are optional in JS, so that input is perfectly valid JS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Python dictionary to JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661051/convert-python-dictionary-to-json-array)

Comment: `python`  has dictionaries that are almost the same as javascript object `JSON`. and python will manipulate the first one same as the js object. and the conversion can only be achieved by manipulating `str` or `dict` object i.e. by performing string operations. By the way, where do you want to use the second one? If it is for javascript, then no need to convert.

Comment: Thanks, for the help. I didn't know properties with quotes were valid JS object keys. However in our codebase that's not the standard so I still needed to convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I did it using regex:

```py
def saveFile(dictionary, fileName):
    jsonStr = json.dumps(dictionary, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False);
    removeQuotes = re.sub("\"([^\"]+)\":", r"\1:", jsonStr);
    fileNameCleaned = fileName.split(" ")[0]
        
    with open(fileNameCleaned + ".ts", "w",encoding='utf_8') as outfile:
        outfile.write("export const " + fileNameCleaned + " = " + removeQuotes + ";")
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python:

```
import json
send_to_js = json.dumps({
 "name": "Paul",
 "age": "20",
 "gender": "male"
})
```

Then in JavaScript:

```
JSON.parse(send_to_js)
// result is {name: 'Paul', age: '20', gender: 'male'}
```