# Dict as a model field

Tags: django, django-models, python-2.7, django-admin

I want to add a `dict` field to a model, display the `dict` on the admin, and be able to edit it from the admin.

For example, I have a relationship

`dict = { 'sister' : rel_score, 'mother' : rel_score, 'father': rel_score}`

where `rel_score` (default = 0) is the score for each relationship. I want to store this `dict` to my model and display it in admin, so that I can assign these rel_score for each relationship on my admin.

Also, any example of how to assign scores (prioritize) to different elements, and return values according to these assigned scores would be really helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store a dictionary on a Django Model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402217/how-to-store-a-dictionary-on-a-django-model)

Comment: That question is quite old. Both django and the available apps have changed a lot since then, so there might be new approaches now.

Comment: Could you use a json-field to represent the dict? https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield

Other apps that also have json modelfields: 
https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/json-fields/

Answer (score 2):

It's not really possible to have a DictField since the underlying database won't support that type of data structure.

You could have a RelationshipScore model to store your relationships and a ForeignKey from it to your existing model (I'll use user as an example). eg:

```
Class RelationshipScore(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    relationship = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    score = models.IntegerField()
```

You could then add functions to your existing model to get the values:

```
class User(models.Model):
    def get_relationship(self, rel):
        return RelationshipScore.objects.get(relationship=rel, user=self)
    def get_lowest_relationship(self):
        return RelationshipScore.objects.filter(user=self).order_by("-score")[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Django 1.8, postgres users also have the option of using an [HStore field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#hstorefield).

```
A field for storing mappings of strings to strings. The Python data type used is a dict.
```

Answer (score 0):

Postgres user can use the jsonfield easely :

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
import json

class Yourmodel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    dict_json = JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):              
        return self.name
```

and within your app :

```
the_dict = {'a':1,'b':2}
Yourmodel.dict_json = json.dumps(the_dict)
Yourmodel.save()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield